# How to change onClick with JavaScript, including function parameter(s)

Tags: javascript

In **JavaScript** I can assign `onclick` by traditional way:

```
button.onclick = engineStop();
```

But how can I assign to `onclick` a function with parameter(s)?

This does not work >>

```
button.onclick = engineStop(this);
```

The function needs to receive `this` parameter to know which button has been clicked on.

Please advice... (no jQuery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
button.onclick = function() {engineStop(this);};
```

Using an anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
function engineStop(param){
    return function(){
        //engineStop function's body here,
        //which uses 'param' argument
    };
}
button.onclick = engineStop(this);
```